# Minecraft Villager for Farming Potatoes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

A villager has been kidnapped and brought far from his village, and has been placed into a farm. I hope for him  to break and replant potatoes, but he does not break the crops or plant any.

Does the farm need to be inside a village? It is a few hundred blocks away from the nearest one.

Comment: Also make sure you have captured a farmer

Comment: What version of minecraft do you use?

Comment: @dly, I think this is probably not a duplicate, because it is stated that the farm is "a few hundred blocks away", so it is unlikely to be the distance. Villagers work differently in 1.14, so it may break due to those differences (I'm not sure what those differences are, I would have to look into that). Or maybe the villager is holding too many potatos, so it doesn't bother about harvesting more (I think it should plant them though)

Comment: @Mr.Bear villagers need a min or max distance as stated in the dupe answer and also a few other things that are mentioned there. So IMHO the answer there answers this question.

Comment: @dly does it account for differences in 1.14? Or are they irrelevant in this case? Maybe the problem in this case is that the villager doesn't have a work station (if that makes sense, as I said, I need to look into villager mechanics). I do agree with you though, if we give updated answers for that question, then that question would also answer this question.

Comment: As long as we don't know the version we can't act upon it. And the general behavior (distance, inventory) should still apply. If there were drastic changes between versions, we would have to close as unclear.

Comment: @dly This is either a duplicate, or unclear, you are right. We should probably update the answers in the other question though, to adress differences in 1.14. and how the farm might fail due to those.

Comment: @Mr.Bear you could as well post a new answer there. That keeps the other answers intact for people playing older versions.

Comment: @dly that is what I meant with "updating", I guess I could have been more clear about that.